# Capturar Identificação de Máquina com C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Bom dia,
Possuo vários computadores com o mesmo IP de saída, como posso pegar qualquer informação que me leve a saber de qual computador veio uma requisição?
Utilizo C# Asp .Net MVC

Comment: O que é um IP de saída? Você está dizendo que várias máquinas estão conectadas em um servidor de rede central que tem um IP? Aí seu site é acessado por este servidor em nome das outras máquinas? Ou você tem acesso às máquinas independente do site? Importa se é ASP.Net?

Comment: o que você deseja saber do computador que veio a requisição, só o nome  pode ser ?

Comment: O sistema funciona na modalidade Intranet?

Comment: Exatamente @bigown, tenho um servidor de rede central com um IP e o site é acessado por uma máquina ligada a este servidor, com isso o IP externo das máquina é sempre o do servidor, consigo pegar alguma informação dá máquina que realmente está acessando ?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Não, é um site publicado mesmo.

Comment: Eu tinha achado isto mas não vai resolver pra você. Nem seria muito confiável também: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/402043/Finding-ip-address-behind-proxy Eu tenho quase certeza que não dá. Só não dou certeza porque pode existir alguma coisa que você tenha controle que ajude nisto. Mas se for algo dentro dos padrões, não dá.

Comment: Você precisa _saber_ qual máquina esta requisitando, ou somente diferenciar cada máquia, sem saber qual é?

Answer (score 1):

A solução é identificar unicamente a máquina. O problema é que a melhor maneira de fazer isso seria obtendo alguma informação do hardware, como o endereço MAC do adaptador de rede ou ainda alguma informação sobre a placa-mãe.

Para isso, é preciso instalar um componente no browser da máquina que está realizando o acesso. Só assim é possível obter mais informações e elaborar um cookie que seja capaz de prover informações sobre o hardware que está realizando o acesso.

Answer (score 1):

Depende um pouco de quanta segurança você precisa nessa identificação.

---

**Diferenciar as máquinas sem garantir a identidade**

Você pode usar cookies. Quando houver um request sem o cookie, você gera uma chave única e registra no cookie. Se uma máquina perder o cookie, um novo será gerado. Você não saberá que máquina é, mas não vai 'confundir' as máquinas.

---

**Diferenciar máquinas, identificando-as (porém não com segurança muito boa)**

Dê uma olhada em [HttpRequestBase.Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.browser.aspx).

Talvez haja alguma informação que você possa usar para distinguir as máquina.
Browser ID pode ser uma delas.

Outra opção, só que ainda mais vulnerável (qualquer usuário bem avançado poderia burlar) seria enviar o IP local por ajax no seu `layout`. Obviamente, neste caso, o IP viria depois do request (inicial pelo menos) e você teria que lidar com isso do lado do servidor - provavelmente identificando a máquina e registrando isso na seção.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var yip2=java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();   
    var yip=yip2.getHostAddress();

</script>
```

Fonte: [Getting local IP address in javascript](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?242538-Getting-local-IP-address-in-javascript)

---

**Diferenciar as máquinas, identificando-as e com segurança**

A priori o jeito direto seria usar um componente instalado na máquina, como o Cigano falou.

Comment: A segunda solução que você propõe não está em c# e sim em java, observe o link. referente ao cookie, acho a melhor opção, realmente.

Comment: Exato, seria para rodar na página no browser, portanto em javascript. Você inseriria o código na html renderizada pela view, além de um mecanismo para a página postar o IP retornado através de javascript.

Comment: Salientando, o código em C#, seja na view, seja no controller, só roda no servidor. O javascript roda no browser, portanto na máquina cliente.

Comment: eu quis dizer, que seu código está errado, que o código que você postou acima é JAVA, não javascript...

Comment: O código anterior funciona em uma página, como javascript. Não tinha as tags script, mas estava correto.